# Getting Run Time error for a Kattis Problem(robotsonagrid)

Tags: python, algorithm, recursion, dynamic-programming, depth-first-search

I am trying to solve this problem (https://open.kattis.com/problems/robotsonagrid).

And when I submit my final code I keep getting a Run Time error in Test case 4. I am not sure what's wrong with my code.

```
n = int(input())
G = [input() for _ in range(n)]

def Compute_Opt(n):
  M = [[None]*n for _ in range(n)]
  M[0][0]=1
  def iter(i, j, M):
    if j == -1 or i == -1:
      return 0
    elif G[i][j] == '#':
      M[i][j] = 0
      return M[i][j]
    elif M[i][j] is not None:
      return M[i][j]
    else :
      M[i][j] = iter(i-1, j, M) + iter(i, j-1, M)
      return M[i][j]

  iter(n-1, n-1, M)
  return M[-1][-1] % (2**31 -1)

def pathornot (n):
  M = [[0]*n for _ in range(n)]
  dir = [
            (1, 0),
            (0, 1),
            (-1, 0),
            (0, -1)
  ]
  def DFS(x ,y):
    if x < 0 or x >= n or y < 0 or y >= n:
      return False
    if M[x][y] == 1:
      return False
    if G[x][y] == '#':
      return False
    M[x][y] = 1
    if x == (n-1) and y ==(n-1):
      return True
    for d in range(len(dir)):
      next_x = x+dir[d][0]
      next_y = y+dir[d][1]
      if DFS(next_x, next_y):
        return True
    return False

  DFS(0,0)
  return M[-1][-1]  

 
out = Compute_Opt(n)

if out == 0:
  if pathornot (n) == 1:
    print("THE GAME IS A LIE")
  else :
    print("INCONCEIVABLE")
else:
  print(out)
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qU06G.png)

Please let me know what I can do to get this code accepted to kattis.com. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

If test case 4 is the 1000x1000 grid which the instructions described, you can assume recursion will fail because the stack depth is only ~1k in CPython. A stack overflow counts as a runtime error.

Converting your solution to work iteratively with a loop for both algorithms passed all cases for me. I'll leave this conversion as an exercise for the reader, but if you're really desperate and want to ruin the party, you can easily find the bottom-up DP version of the "ways to reach the bottom-right in a grid moving right and down" algorithm and the iterative version of DFS on the internet.

Side notes/suggestions:

- Always use [Black](https://black.vercel.app) to format your code. Lack of ample whitespace around operators and in indentation makes Python code difficult to read.
- Don't redefine standard library functions like `iter` and `dir`. This can easily manifest as a bug, or at least harms readability.
- Follow [PEP-8](https://pep8.org/) naming conventions: functions and variables are `lower_snake_case` and classes are `UpperCamelCase`.
- Pass `G` as a parameter to your functions instead of accessing it globally.
- Use booleans `True`/`False` rather than 0 and 1.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestions. Sorry, I'm a beginner, what I can do now is just let it run.  I'm terribly sorry since my code is a piece of shit.  I hope you'll forgive me.